# TypeError: __init__() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'user_name', 'age', 'email', and 'gender'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

This is my flask app. I got:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'user_name', 'age', 'email', and 'gender'
```

I tried to fix the `__init__()` but nothing changes. I am new to flask and have no idea what to do and stuck with this error for 2 days. I feel really bad.

```
#database connection 
class friends(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    user_id = db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True)
    user_name = db.Column(db.String)
    age = db.Column(db.Integer)
    email = db.Column(db.String)
    gender = db.Column(db.String)

    def __init__(self, user_id, user_name, age, email,gender):
       self.id = user_id
       self.name = user_name
       self.age = age
       self.email = email
       self.gender = gender

#route
@app.route('/add', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        add_usr_id = request.form['new_usr_id']
        new_id = friends( user_id = add_usr_id)
        add_usr_name = request.form['new_usr_name']
        new_name = friends( user_name = add_usr_name)
        add_usr_age = request.form['new_usr_age']
        new_age = friends(age = add_usr_age)
        add_usr_email = request.form['new_usr_email']
        new_email = friends(email = add_usr_email)
        add_usr_gender = request.form['new_usr_gender']
        new_gender = friends(gender = add_usr_gender)
        commit_user = friends( new_id, new_name, new_age, new_email, new_gender)
        db.session.add(commit_user)
        db.session.commit()
        message = "The record for {add_usr_name} was added."
        return render_template('add.html', message=message)
    else:
        return render_template('add.html')
```

And I got the traceback error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/waiyan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2548, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/waiyan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2528, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/Users/waiyan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2525, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/waiyan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1822, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/waiyan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/waiyan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1796, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "/Users/waiyan/Desktop/Flask/Flask2/app.py", line 40, in add
    new_id = friends( user_id = add_usr_id)
TypeError: __init__() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'user_name', 'age', 'email', and 'gender'
```

Comment: Your init method doesn't seem to be inside the class. Need to indent 1 level.

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: Ok, yes, I see your update. So how does that error message relate to the first one you posted? Which one is the real one? Does this mean that you formatted the code for `class friends` incorrectly in this post?

Comment: sorry for my bad asking format. I am new to coding. I fixed the questions @quamrana

Comment: Ok, you still need to post the full error traceback. The full one also has the line of code that the error relates to.

Comment: @quamrana already added the traceback sir

Comment: No, I see a single line with the error type.  There should be a whole stack trace that goes with it.

Comment: Ok, now we have proof that the error in on the line: `new_id = friends( user_id = add_usr_id)`. The short answer is to look at the answer from `Vashishth Patel`. The longer answer is a question. What does that line mean to you? Why create an instance of `friends` with one parameter?

Comment: The default ORM constructor accepts keyword arguments and it will not error if a column value is missing.  I would delete the `__init__` method so that `friends()`, `friends(name='Alice')` and so on will work without error (assuming there are no other constraints).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the error is because of the indentation.
Try to add index level 1 before `__init__` function.
Below is the code with correction.

```
#database connection 
class friends(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    user_id = db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True)
    user_name = db.Column(db.String)
    age = db.Column(db.Integer)
    email = db.Column(db.String)
    gender = db.Column(db.String)

    def __init__(self, user_id, user_name, age, email,gender):
        self.id = user_id
        self.name = user_name
        self.age = age
        self.email = email
        self.gender = gender

#route
@app.route('/add', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        add_usr_id = request.form['new_usr_id']
        add_usr_name = request.form['new_usr_name']
        add_usr_age = request.form['new_usr_age']
        add_usr_email = request.form['new_usr_email']
        add_usr_gender = request.form['new_usr_gender']
        commit_user = friends(new_id, new_name, new_age, new_email, new_gender)
        db.session.add(commit_user)
        db.session.commit()
        message = "The record for {add_usr_name} was added."
        return render_template('add.html', message=message)
    else:
        return render_template('add.html')
```

Comment: I made Indentation and this Error came back "TypeError: __init__() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'user_name', 'age', 'email', and 'gender' "

Comment: Hey @WaiYan! Instead of adding parameter every time, you first get all the data from post and at last just do `commit_user = friends( new_id, new_name, new_age, new_email, new_gender)`. I guess this will work. I am modifying the above answer. Please check that.

Comment: It didn't work also

Answer (score 1):

try to use

```
commit_user = friends(user_id=new_id, user_name=new_name, age=new_age, email=new_email, gender=new_gender)
```

instead of

```
commit_user = friends( new_id, new_name, new_age, new_email, new_gender)
```

Comment: I used your code and It gave me back Data Error